# How to iterate through list groups independent of each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, iteration

I'm trying to create a simple toggle for 3 list groups, with multiple list items within each. Each list group can only have 1 active item at a time, for a total of 3 active items (one per list group).

My code only deactivates the list group active class on the last list group, what am I missing?

See JSbin: https://jsbin.com/hizezu

Please include comments in your answer code so I can understand why it works. Thanks

HTML

```
                      <div id="selectPatientCategories">
                            <div class="list-group">
                                <h4>Select Doctor</h4>
                                <hr>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Justice Freedom</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Martin Fabio</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Jenny Walter</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Loius Von Winkle</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Mary McDoctors</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Freethinker Liver</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Cognitive Thinker</a>
                            </div>
                       <div class="list-group">
                                <h4>Select Doctor</h4>
                                <hr>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Justice Freedom</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Martin Fabio</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Jenny Walter</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Loius Von Winkle</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Mary McDoctors</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Freethinker Liver</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Cognitive Thinker</a>
                            </div>
                    <div class="list-group">
                                <h4>Select Doctor</h4>
                                <hr>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Justice Freedom</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Martin Fabio</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Jenny Walter</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Loius Von Winkle</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Mary McDoctors</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Freethinker Liver</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Cognitive Thinker</a>
                            </div>
                      </div>
```

And the JS

```
  // Vanilla JS version of apply class "active" on click of .list-group-item

    var listGroup = document.querySelectorAll('#selectPatientCategories .list-group');
    //console.log(listGroup);

    var cats = document.querySelectorAll('a.list-group-item');
    //console.log(cats);

    // For each category list group
    var listGroupIndex = 0, listGroupLength = listGroup.length;
    for (; listGroupIndex < listGroupLength; listGroupIndex++) {
        var thisListGroup = listGroup[listGroupIndex];
        //console.log(thisListGroup);

        // For each category list item
        var catIndex = 0, catLength = cats.length;
        for (; catIndex < catLength; catIndex++) {
            var thiscat = cats[catIndex];
            //console.log(listGroupIndex);

            // Click function on list item
            thiscat.addEventListener('click', function () {
                //console.log(thisListGroup);

                var thisListGroupCats = thisListGroup.querySelectorAll('a.list-group-item');
                //console.log(thisListGroupCats);

                var rmcatIndex = 0, rmCatLength = thisListGroupCats.length;
                //console.log(rmCatLength);
                for (; rmcatIndex < rmCatLength; rmcatIndex++) {

                    rmthiscat = thisListGroupCats[rmcatIndex];
                    //console.log(rmthiscat);

                    rmthiscat.classList.remove('active');
                    this.classList.add('active');

                }

            }); // End click function
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why did you tagged jquery?

Comment: Looking for vanilla javascript answer but open to jquery versions as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overdoing for what is necessary with your current implementation. All you need is just to iterate through the current list-group and for each 'a' remove class 'active' and then add class 'active' to the item which was clicked.

```
// target an 'a' element with class='list-group-item' inside an element which has class 'list-group'.
$(".list-group a[class='list-group-item']").click(function()
{
    // get the 'list-group' element of the current 'a' element clicked.
    // $(this) refers to the element object which invoked the event.
    var listGroup = $(this).parent();
    // look for each 'a' element within the current 'list-group' and remove class 'active' if it has so.
     $(listGroup).find("a").removeClass("active");

    // add class 'active' to the 'a' element which was clicked
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/j2c59j9j/2/

Comment: You can replace your `each` with this `$(listGroup).find("a").removeClass("active")`

Comment: That's right. Thanks for pointing that out. Updated the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Based on your answer, I was able to create a vanilla js version of it that also works.

Answer (score 0):

I created an pure javascript solution based on DinoMyte's answer:
https://jsbin.com/vexoli

```
    //Vanilla JS version of apply class "active" on click of .list-group-item

    var listGroup = document.querySelectorAll('#selectPatientCategories .list-group');
    //console.log(listGroup);

    var cats = document.querySelectorAll('a.list-group-item');
    //console.log(cats);

    // For each category list item
    var catIndex = 0, catLength = cats.length;
    for (; catIndex < catLength; catIndex++) {
        var thiscat = cats[catIndex];
        //console.log(listGroupIndex);

        // Click function on list item
        thiscat.addEventListener('click', function () {
            //console.log(thisListGroup);

            //Get the parent .list-group
            thisListGroup = this.parentElement;
            thisListGroupCats = thisListGroup.querySelectorAll('a.list-group-item');

            //console.log(thisListGroupCats);

            // For each category .list-group-item within this listGroup
            var listGroupIndex = 0, listGroupCatsLength = thisListGroupCats.length;
            for (; listGroupIndex < listGroupCatsLength; listGroupIndex++) {

                // Focus on just this .list-group being iterated
                rmThisCat = thisListGroupCats[listGroupIndex];
                rmThisCat.classList.remove('active');

            }
            this.classList.add('active');

        }); // End click function
    }
```